# How can I use conditonal operator in OrderBy function

Tags: c#

```
bookingInfo.CreditCardList = airUserCreditCardList
  .Distinct()
  .OrderBy(o => o.Text)
  .ToList();
```

I am trying to order the list based on the value inside the `Text` property.Is there a way I can order the list only if the Object's property Text has value "Primary".

My list looks like this

````
     Text="abc",Code="123"----0th index
        Text ="Select",Code="1233"--1st Index
        Text="Primary",Code="0000"--2ndIndex```

But i want it to look like this only if the Primary card is present in the list 

    ```
Text="Primary",Code="0000"--0th Index
    Text ="Select",Code="1233"--1st Index
        Text ="abc",Code="123"--2nd Index
````

Comment: Can you give some examples illustrating what you mean by "order the list only if the value of Text is primary else no ordering should occur"?

Comment: It's not clear, if you only want to order by records which text is "primary" you mean you want to see all "primary"-credit-cards first and then rest?

Comment: It's unclear what is "if value of `Text` is primary". Something like this: `.OrderBy(o => o.Text != "primary")`

Comment: Why "abc" comes after "Select" if "Primary" is in the list? I understand that "Primary" comes first but if you would order by `Text` the word "abc" would come before "Select". It's also not the original order, so it seems suddenly "abc" comes at the end for no reason. Explain the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by `bool` value (note, however, that `false < true`):

```
  bookingInfo.CreditCardList = airUserCreditCardList
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(o => !o.Text.Contains("Text=\"Primary\""))
    .ToList();
```